# validate list of error

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have a file that contains some specified error.
in want to grep error from log and if I find those specied error then only I want to receive email.

```
grep error log
error1
error2
error3
error4
error6
error7

specified error list(of 30 errors) for which i want to receive email
error3
error7
.....
error30
```

I want to receive email if error matches to specified error list like error 3 and error 7 and so on..... dont want email for the error that is not in specified error list.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a list of error patterns in `patterns.txt`:

```
error3
error7
```

And your logs are in a file called `all.log`. Then you could generate a temporary file with the errors that match your specified patterns, and if the file is non-empty, then email it to yourself:

```
grep -f patterns.txt all.log > /tmp/matches.log
test -s /tmp/matches.log || mailx -s 'interesting errors' you@example.com < /tmp/matches.log
```

You can do it without a temporary file by storing the result of `grep` in a variable:

```
matches=$(grep -f patterns.txt all.log)
test "$matches" && echo "$matches" | mailx -s 'interesting errors' you@example.com
```